# NetBeans 6.8 marks keywords as fault

Tags: c++, netbeans6.8, keyword

I have just installed NetBeans 6.8. on Ubuntu 10.04 and it marks c++ keywords such as "using" or "namespace" as a fault. I checked that it compiles with g++ and I found an answer to that already here, but there it was a bug in Netbeans which had been fixed via updates within a few days. When I try to update, it tells me, I have the latest version...no surprise...
If I define me a class and want to use it in the main file, it does neither work. The header file of my class is included ;-)
And actually, when I write something like myClass::myMethod(int n){ myClass::Variable +=n;} it does not even accept the definition of n in the round brackets...

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: If a poster here answers your question it's polite to mark the question as answered (with the check mark beside the question you feel answers the question best).

Answer (score 0):

The latest version is 6.91. You might have to download it again from netbeans.org if you're having issues with the update. Package manager may not have the latest version.

When you say you have errors are they when compiling or is the IDE underlining them in red before you compile? The IDE tries to be helpful but it's not very accurate sometimes.